# How to toggle class using pure javascript in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, toggle

I have a `<div>`, and I want to toggle its classes on hover.

Here is my code:

```
function a(){
    this.classList.toggle('first');
    this.classList.toggle('sec');
}
document.querySelector('#container').addEventListener('click', a );
```

I know there is no problem in my html or css. It is just that I have to change and put something in place of `click`, but I don't know what.

Please help!!

Comment: why not just use `:hover` in css ?  more here: http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/:hover

Comment: One reason reason is [this](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=122746) :)

Answer (score 63):

Hover event is called "mouseenter" instead of "click".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function a(){
        this.classList.toggle('first');
        this.classList.toggle('sec');
    }
    document.querySelector('#container').addEventListener('mouseenter', a )
    document.querySelector('#container').addEventListener('mouseleave', a )
</script>
```

Comment: When using `ID` (`#container`) the oldschool `getElementById()` is almost 10x faster than `querySelector()`

Comment: Note that the `.toggle()` method is not supported on IE9 and under.
See [MDN Docs on `classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Comment: In some edge cases, JS is better for complete cross browser compatibility.

Answer (score 10):

While [**Tom Chung**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3041843/tom-chung)'s approach definitely works, it's better to give `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` their own handler :

```js
var container = document.querySelector('#container');

container.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
        this.classList.remove('first');
        this.classList.add('second');
})
container.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
        this.classList.add('first');
        this.classList.remove('second');
})
```

```css
.first {
    background: green;
}

.second {
    background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="first">
    TEST
</div>
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/crf27dms/))