# Javascript(not jquery) button onclick, function changes class of button calling function

Tags: javascript, function, button

I know you can change the class of a button using

```
 document.getElementById("ID1").setAttribute("class", "NewClass");
```

But say i wanted to change the class to `active` if the button is clicked, is there anyway to do this without assigning an ID to the buttons ?
I also don't want to change all buttons with this class and am aware you can use get element by class as well.

The buttons are generated by another piece of javascript and look like

```
    <button class="btn" onclick="myFunction(this.innerHTML)">A</button>
    <button class="btn" onclick="myFunction(this.innerHTML)">B</button>
    <button class="btn" onclick="myFunction(this.innerHTML)">C</button>
    <button class="btn" onclick="myFunction(this.innerHTML)">D</button>
    <button class="btn" onclick="myFunction(this.innerHTML)">F</button>
    <button class="btn" onclick="myFunction(this.innerHTML)">G</button>
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Also if you need any more information just let me know.

Comment: can you change myFunction()???????

Comment: Instead of using this.innerHTML just use this then you have access to the button that was clicked instead of of only the text. So then you can do this.setAttribute("class", "NewClass"); in the function.

Comment: @rajeshkakawat Yeah it does something else at the minute, its just to get a value.

Comment: @Brian, would i use `this.setAttribute("class", "NewClass")` in the function, or would i use whatever the variable is. E.g If it was `MyFunction(x)` would i use `x.setAttribute("class", "NewClass")` ?

Comment: I added an answer with what i mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<button class="btn" onclick="myFunction(this)">A</button>


<script>
function myFunction(button) {
    var text = button.innerHTML;
    // do whatever with text that you were doing before...
    button.setAttribute("class", "active");
}
</script>
```

Comment: That works perfectly cheers :) Can't believe i didn't think of trying that!

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function a(){
        this.classList.toggle('first');
        this.classList.toggle('sec');
    }
    document.querySelector('#container').addEventListener('mouseenter', a )
    document.querySelector('#container').addEventListener('mouseleave', a )
</script>
```

from [How to toggle class using pure javascript in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20301235/how-to-toggle-class-using-pure-javascript-in-html)

Comment: I want it for if it is clicked, not hover, but this is useful. +1.Thankyou :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Test Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="css/style.css" />

    </head>
<body>
    <button class="btn" onclick="myFunction(this)">A</button>
    <button class="btn" onclick="myFunction(this)">B</button>
    <button class="btn" onclick="myFunction(this)">C</button>
    <button class="btn" onclick="myFunction(this)">D</button>
    <button class="btn" onclick="myFunction(this)">F</button>
    <button class="btn" onclick="myFunction(this)">G</button>

    <script>
                function myFunction(object){
                    object.className = object.className + " btn-active";
                }
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would this not change it for all buttons though ?

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

**html**

```
<button class="btn" onclick="myFunction(this)">A</button>
```

**javascript**

```
function myFunction(btn){
    btn.setAttribute("class", "NewClass");// change class

    btn.innerHTML // use your inner html here
}
```

Comment: The other answer was posted before yours so i accepted that one, i appreciate the help though :) +1

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you want

```
(function() {
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
    if(buttons && buttons.length > 0) {
        for(var i=0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            var button = buttons[i];
            button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                this.classList.toggle('active');
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

You're attaching a click event handler to all the buttons.

http://jsfiddle.net/doiks14/zn6dgn0m/5/

Comment: This is very useful, thanks :) I will probably move onto toggling the buttons so +1

Comment: Also does this use any jquery ?

Comment: No, this is just JavaScript

Comment: I looked up the toggle function and it looks like it's a jquery addon ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList - this is a native JavaScript function, although you may want to use polyfill if you want to support older browsers or simply use an alternative way of toggling.

Comment: Yep looks like the jquery one is different, its just searching anything to do with javascript on google comes up with jquery things and i couldn't find it relating to just javascript. Something similar to the page you linked is what i was looking for though so thanks again, I appreciate the help :)